# How can I resample polygons in postgis to a lower resolution?

Tags: sql, postgresql, maps, gis, postgis

I have a table in Postgres (with Postgis) that looks like this:

| geom | val |
| --- | --- |
| POLYGON(...coordinates) | 80 |
| POLYGON(...coordinates) | 72 |

Each one of these polygons represents a 30m diamond square on the map. I am using 4326 as the SRID.

I want to create bigger diamonds with 1km each (lower resolution) so I can retrieve data for the map in different zoom levels.

**My Attempts**

After some googling, I figured out that I could use raster functions to resample my bins (like st_resample), but I would have to convert my polygons to raster first.

How can I create 1km bin sizes from this data?

I have tried many ways of converting those polygons to a single raster without success.

```sql
-- Creating an empty raster:
create table empty_raster (
    rast raster
);

with
-- First I calculated the bounding box for all of the polygons:
bbox as (SELECT ST_Extent(geom) as geom FROM my_data)
insert into empty_raster
-- Then I create an empty raster with that size
select (
        -- I probably don't need this SetSRID
        ST_SetSRID(
            ST_MakeEmptyRaster(
                -- width/height
                ceil((ST_XMax(bbox.geom) - ST_XMin(bbox.geom)))::int,
                ceil((ST_YMax(bbox.geom) - ST_YMin(bbox.geom)))::int,
                -- position
                ST_XMin(bbox.geom)::float8,
                ST_YMax(bbox.geom)::float8,
                -- bin size (what scale should I use here? Meters?)
                30,
                0,
                0,
                4326
            ),
            4326
        )
    ) AS rast FROM bbox;
```

But I would need a way of populating/burning it, but I have no idea how to match each one of the polygons to a pixel in the raster nor how to resample it later.

**The question**

How can I create 1km square-diamonds by extracting the mean of all of the 30m squares values that fall into the bigger ones?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far. In general we don't use resolution with vector graphics, may be you want to simplify them?

Comment: Ok, I updated my question to be clearer on what I'm trying to do

Comment: Well first, don't mix degrees and metres so you'll need to reproject. Then can you simply union together existing polygons to make your bigger ones? Maybe a picture can help